# Updating JPanel content in JFrame by using a frame state variable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, components

I'm trying to find a way how to update a panel content after changing a state variable.

Concretely in the example below, there is simple JPanel inside JFrame with two buttons. When the app starts, its state variable ("window") equals "home" so home button should be invisible. After clicking on the page button the state variable change and so both buttons visibility should change after frame repainting. (i.e. the page button should disappear and the home button should appear).

In this case, it is possible to solve it without the state variable just using setVisibility() method for buttons. But in my app, I would like to have more JComponetns connected to the state variable. Is there a way how to do it?

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

    public class JPanelUpdateTest {

        private JFrame frame;
        private String window = "home";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        JPanelUpdateTest window = new JPanelUpdateTest();
                        window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        public JPanelUpdateTest() {
            initialize();
        }


        private void initialize() {
            frame = new JFrame("JPanelUpdateTest");
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JButton btnHome = new JButton("home");
            btnHome.setVisible(window == "home" ? false : true);
            btnHome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    window = "page";
                    panel.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            });
            panel.add(btnHome);

            JButton btnPage = new JButton("page");
            btnPage.setVisible(window == "page" ? false : true);
            btnPage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    window = "home";
                    panel.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            });
            panel.add(btnPage);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that initialize is only being called once, at object creation, and it **should** only be called once, and because of this the `setVisible(...)` code is not being called from the ActionListeners. Instead you need to put the mechanisms for changing the views within the ActionListeners themselves, not just changing state, not unless you are using a "bound property" and PropertyChangeListeners.

Myself, I'd recommend using a CardLayout to assist you in your swapping, and rather than directly changing Strings, call a public method of your class -- planning for when and if the ActionListener (controller) code is ever removed from the view class.

Also, regarding:

```
btnPage.setVisible(window == "page" ? false : true);
```

don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Also, if all you want to do is change the text and behavior that a JButton is doing, then you can change this easily by using `setText(...)` to change only the text, and for a deeper change, call `setAction(Action action)` to change text and state.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I see... So, if I set the component as a class  constant in order to edit it by a method, it would work. It means lots of constants, so I'll try the CardLayout instead. Thanks for the equals(), too. I really appreciate it.